# Research on neural networks mimicking behavior

Tags: neural-networks, modeling, noise, reproducible-research

My question is regarding neural networks mimicking noise specifically.

The idea.
I have clinically clean image generated by a ray tracer and a neural network (type does not matter) that is mimicking noise of the environment. Environment meaning: Perlin noise, lens noise, noise from the sun, noise from fog, or for behavior, etc.

I would like to produce the nose onto the ray tracer images, I'm aware that for each type one should use a new network.

What I would like to know if someone tried something like this and is there research published regarding something like that. The noise is specifically for images and 2D matrices.

Comment: What does it mean for a neural network to mimic noise?

Comment: I do not know what you mean now. My idea is to have a neural network that creates kind of a mask that is used as a over layer on and image for example (mimics the behavior of a noise). That could be for example modeling Perlin noise or some environment behavior like smoke or fog.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have a neural network inspect an image and create a noise pattern so that you can superimpose that pattern on an image of interest?

Comment: Yes that is the idea.